# Custom stippled pen

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm trying to draw what amounts to a screen-tone effect over an existing image, but I'd like to leave an area blank.  Think of how spotlights in old games are sometimes done, where most of the image is darkened, and but part of it is the "normal" color.
To do this, I need my overlay to be transparent (since the original image has to show through).  I'm also drawing this with `wxDC.DrawCircle(...)` (with a transparent brush), since it allows me to not draw over a circular area.

Problem is, the stipple (screen tone effect) isn't transparent, it's solid.  I've tried just about everything I can think of, but nothing seems to work.
My current code is roughly like this:

```
const char* ScreenToneColor[] =
{
    /* columns rows colors chars-per-pixel */
    "3 3 2 1",
    "X c Black",
    "O c None",
    /* pixels */
    "OOO",
    "OXO",
    "OOO"
};

CustomPanel::CustomPanel(wxWindow* parent)
    : wxPanel(parent, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(151, 151))
{
    SetBackgroundStyle(wxBG_STYLE_PAINT);
    // MemberVariables
    m_Stipple = wxBitmap(wxImage(ScreenToneColor));
    m_ScreenTone = wxPen(*wxBLACK, 2 * VeryLargeRadius, wxPENSTYLE_STIPPLE);
    m_ScreenTone.SetStipple(m_Stipple);
}

// Supplied with a wxAutoBufferedDC
void CustomPanel::Render(wxDC&  dc)
{
    dc.SetBrush(*wxGREEN_BRUSH);
    dc.DrawRectangle(m_PanelRectange);
    // "fade out" trimmed areas by drawing a ring.
    dc.SetBrush(*wxTRANSPARENT_BRUSH);
    dc.SetPen(m_ScreenTone);
    dc.DrawCircle(m_AnimatedCenter, VeryLargeRadius + m_VisibleRadius);
}
```

I've tried supplying the mask, using the different stipple masks (avoiding `wxPENSTYLE_STIPPLE_MASK_OPAQUE`), etc.
I'm on Windows 10 and compiling against wxWidgets 3.1, although the project is being built/run on other OSs, and possibly a lower library version.

Comment: can you try the Git HEAD? And check how the other platforms behave?

Comment: I can try getting Git HEAD tomorrow or something, but I have no way to test on the other platforms myself.

Comment: ok, please check the HEAD, and ask someone for the other platform.

Comment: also, just to think about - http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/1110. It means GTK2 port does not implement the feature and GTK3 possibly works. No idea about OSX/Cocoa.

Comment: @igor - I've realized that, even if git/HEAD worked, or it functioned on other platforms, it doesn't really matter:  The built project would use a stable package, and it still has to work on Windows.  It's fine if the answer ends up being "You can't do that", but I'd still have to make it work "as is", essentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wxDC` doesn't support transparency with just the only exception of drawing bitmaps with alpha channel. If you want to do anything involving alpha, you need to use `wxGraphicsContext` and related classes. I'm not sure if GDI+ or Direct2D implementations of it currently handle this correctly, but after checking the code it seems like at least the former one should.

Comment: Right you are (now that I know what to look for...)!  Do you think you could link the relevant documentation for future interested readers?

Comment: Do you mean something [like this](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_d_c.html#dc_alpha_support)?

Comment: Yeah.  Although I haven't been able to get it working with `wxGCDC` yet either, may need to try a different one.  Looks nicer otherwise, though.